# Set Default Page Layout for Record Type in XML File

Tags: deployment, page-layout, salesforcedx-cli, record-type, xml

Can I add a default page layout to a record type xml file?

I'm deploying an sfdx package to various client organizations and I want to set a default page layout in each record type XML file. I can't deploy the profiles themselves because the client orgs all have different custom profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default page layout is, unfortunately, in the profile. You'll need to create a system that retrieves each org's profiles, updates the appropriate page layout settings, then deploy those changes.